# User logout , Browser tab closing event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I log out the user , if all tabs closed, How to get browser tab unique id , so that I can add that to local storage on before load and remove on before unload .

Here what I tried:

Here I am using localstorage and session storage

Conditions checked :

1) **First load :** setting localstorage variable and sessionstorage on load method

2) **Another tab opened :** Increasign localstorage onload method

3) **Refresh the same page :** If sessionStorage exists not increasing localstorage count

4) **If web Tab closing:**  Onbeforeunloading method -> Decreasing localstorage count

5) **Onbeforeunloading last tab:** logging out , like : count ===0 => calling  logout method.

6) Everything working fine count is also decreasing,but when it comes to last tab logout method not calling

Comment: Why not use session storage, which was created precisely to be cleared when the user closes the tab? In any case, you'll need to provide some evidence of research and what you've tried to avoid getting downvotes.

Comment: sure @Heretic Monkey , I forgot to add those things updating original post

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't specifically what you asked for, I think setting the cookie that holds the auth token to "ephemeral" avoids this whole issue. It requires you to have access to the web server, though.

https://stormpath.com/blog/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-node-dot-js-sessions